# SharePoint Workflow 2013 Extracting Info From String

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, workflow2013

I have a form that has the ability to do a repeating section. the data is stored in "XML" like although the tags are quite ugly. Anyway, the output is something like this: 
01/01/1900 00:00:002090Name: John Doe<_x0037_57001aa-3589-490c-b2e2-3bcb2b3d43aa type="System.String"><_x0034_a79d95e-63b5-47ff-ba15-5ca535569237 type="System.Boolean">False01/01/1900 00:00:002090Name: Jane Doe<_x0037_57001aa-3589-490c-b2e2-3bcb2b3d43aa type="System.String"><_x0034_a79d95e-63b5-47ff-ba15-5ca535569237 type="System.Boolean">False.

I want to be able to grab all the data points that say Name: String. I know I will have to write a loop and do some parsing, but the Out of the Box WF options seem limited. I searched around and [Found Some Add-ons](http://spworkflowactions.codeplex.com/releases/view/119911) I can use with WF 2013 but it doesn't appear to be solving my issue. Any direction on how to tackle this? I also thought about the Trim String method, but that wasn't getting me anywhere either.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using the parsing string options. It's kinda weird how you have to work through it, but OOTB will do this for you with a little tinkering.